# Tab autocompletion of accented characters with oh-my-zsh doesn't work

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I am not able to properly display autocompleted filenames that contain accented characters like `ã` in my shell configuration of `zsh` and [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

I've created a filename `cão.txt` to demonstrate this issue. If you're interested, that means `dog` in Portuguese.

So, when I try to autocomplete like `cat c<tab>`, this happens:

```
% cat ca<0303>o.txt
hi dog
```

and `echo $0` gives me: `-zsh`

But, if I go to a "plain" `zsh` session the exact same autocomplete works ok:

```
% zsh
% echo $0
zsh
%  cat cão.txt
hi dog
```

My `locale` is like this:

```
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

and the `LANG` variable I tried it empty, with `"en_US.UTF-8"` and also `"pt_PT.UTF-8"`. Also, I double-checked the `locale` settings are exactly the same before and after going to the "plain" `zsh` session.

Also it works the same way in both the default terminal OSX application and iTerm2.

I'm using zsh version `5.0.7`.

Here is my [.zshrc](https://github.com/nunoh/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc) file, as well as other dotfiles I'm using.

I've tried uninstalling `oh-my-zsh` and install it in either the automatic and manual way, always with the same problem of displaying accented characters with autocomplete.

Comment: What zsh version do you have? I have 4.3.17 and `cão.txt` is autocompleted with `ã` character. I also have `LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Just to clarify: In step 3. you start `bash` from within your running *zsh* session and in step 5. you exit the *bash* session back to the original zsh session? All in the same terminal? And any other sessions remain unaffected? Also do you have anything special in your *bash* configuration? For example calls to `tput` or anything else, that would affect the terminal emulator. Could you perhaps post a link to your configuration (bash and zsh) or post it in your question (if it is not to long?).

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Hm.. Really? Good news then. Should be something in my setup rather than in zsh itself. I've updated my answer accordingly to your question. I'm using zsh version 5.0.7 and bash 4.3.30. Thanks for your reply! Any other ideas?

Comment: @Adaephon: I do that all in the same terminal session yes. I've just tried it and other terminal sessions remain unaffected, that is, in another session, separate from the one that starts in zsh and goes to bash and back to zsh, in that other one the problem still remains. Also, I have no bash configuration files at all. And for my `.zshrc` please I've included a link in my updated to my dotfiles. Thanks for your reply. Any other ideas?

Comment: `bash` may read `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` or other files sourced from there. Does completion work correctly in a zsh session started with `zsh -f`? Does the behaviour change if you start and exit `ksh` or `tcsh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: @nunos: I updated zsh to 5.0.7, copied all your dotfiles and ohmyzsh and sourced them and I still can see `ã` autocompleted. I use uxterm on Linux. If you change `ã` to another diacritical character, are they autocompleted correctly? How did you enter `ã` character? I copied it from your post into my terminal.

Comment: @Adaephon: If I start it with `zsh -f` it works OK! All the other shells work equally ok as well! Any idea why this is happening then?

Comment: There's one thing that I think could be related `echo $0` with my configuration zsh with oh-my-zsh returns `-zsh` whereas if I am using `zsh` it returns exactly `zsh`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Really? It worked with you? Wow.. That's truly strange.. I'm starting to run out of ideas here.. I've rewritten my answer for clarity. Now I know it has to do with my zsh + oh-my-zsh setup somehow, but still can't pinpoint what exactly and how to fix it.

Comment: This is a bug of `zsh` on many versions of `Mac OS X`, see: http://superuser.com/a/1060564/233562 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like normal default `zsh` behavior. Whether combining characters are displayed combined during autocompletion is controlled by the `combining_chars` shell option. To have it complete to `cão`, put this in your `~/.zshrc` file.

```
setopt combining_chars
```

I can't reproduce your behavior where this is the default for non-login (`zsh` vs `-zsh`) shells.

In the case of `zsh -f` and the non-login `zsh`, they are sourcing only `/etc/zshenv`, and not the other configuration files. Maybe you have your `/etc/zshenv` configured to `setopt combining_chars` and something later in the initialization sequence is resetting it.